# Vagrant remove one of many boxes with different versions

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to run vagrant 1.7.4 on a windows 7 machine. I have vagrant installed along with a few boxes. I am trying to delete all of my boxes and start fresh. Below is a list of my boxes:

```
vagrant box list
```

> laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.4.2)
>
> ubuntu/trusty64   (virtualbox, 20151208.1.0)
>
> ubuntu/trusty64   (virtualbox, 20151217.0.0)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
vagrant box remove ubuntu/trusty64
```

> You requested to remove the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' with provider
>   'virtualbox'. This box has multiple versions. You must
>   explicitly specify which version you want to remove with
>   the `--box-version` flag. The available versions for this
>   box are:
>
> - 20151208.1.0
> - 20151217.0.0

```
box remove --box-version ubuntu/trusty64 20151208.1.0
```

> 'box' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

```
vagrant box remove --box ubuntu/trusty64 -version 20151208.1.0
```

> vagrant: no version found in package ersion

How do I remove this vagrant box with multiple versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to:

C:\Users\username\.vagrant.d\boxes

and manually deleting all the boxes.

Answer (score 4):

```
vagrant box remove ubuntu/trusty64 --box-version 20151208.1.0
```

Source : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html