# Truly delete all traces of a Vagrant machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant, packer

How do I remove all traces of a Vagrant box without having to go into the file system manually?

I am creating a custom box using Packer, building and destroying a lot of test cases.  When finished with a test case, I run

```
vagrant destroy
```

The `vagrant help` describes this command as

> stops and deletes all traces of the vagrant machine

Everything seems well with the world.  However, when I create a new box, after a brand new installation, I notice that my message of the day says the VM was created several days ago.  It turns out boxes are (also) stored in `.vagrant.d\boxes`.  Vagrant is using those boxes rather than, or in addition to, the boxes created by Packer, which live in a completely different location.

The vagrant documentation for [`vagrant destroy`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy.html) recommends using `vagrant box remove`.

Now, there's still a box in `.vagrant.d\boxes` directory.  Using `vagrant box remove` requires a "name".

If I run `vagrant box list`, it says

> There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.

Apparently Vagrant doesn't know about this other box.  Yet if I run `vagrant global-status`, I get an output like

```
id       name    provider   state    directory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
47d1c7c  default virtualbox poweroff C:/some/path
```

So, Vagrant *can* see some box.  Trying to use `vagrant box remove`, neither the "name" or "id" references work:

```
C:\some\path>vagrant box remove default
The box you requested to be removed could not be found. No
boxes named 'default' could be found.

C:\some\path>vagrant box remove 47d1c7c
The box you requested to be removed could not be found. No
boxes named '47d1c7c' could be found.
```

Of course, I can [just delete the boxes by hand](https://superuser.com/questions/1113532/vagrant-remove-one-of-many-boxes-with-different-versions) in `.vagrant.d\boxes`.

It seems like my understanding of what Vagrant means by 'box', 'destroy', 'remove', and, well, almost all the terms involved here, isn't correct.  I can't make sense of it all.  There's a Vagrant VM directory which contains one box, but then there's the box Packer creates, and there's yet another box in `.vagrant.d\boxes`.  To `destroy` a box removes some of the traces, but not all.  The `list` command sees some boxes but not others.  It all appears very inconsistent.

I'm creating CentOS 7 guests on a Windows 7 host, if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Vagrant creates an internal Virtual Machine related to a downloaded box.

To delete all data from the Virtual Machine and Box I do recommend removing the box and also destroying the virtual machine.

To list the boxes execute the command:

```
vagrant box list
```

To remove a box execute the command:

```
vagrant box remove box/name
```

To destroy the Virtual Machine

```
vagrant destroy vm-name
```

You wiped out all data.

Answer (score 0):

@Loren Ipsum  I did a backup of my whole directory with VagrantFile, so I removed the whole directory. Doing a `#vagrant global-status --prune` remove all from this list. Delete `.vagrant.d\boxes`

```
C:\tools\Cmder
λ vagrant global-status --prune
id       name   provider state  directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or,
you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were
started with an older version of Vagrant.

C:\tools\Cmder
λ vagrant box list
centos/7                (hyperv, 1905.1)
debian/buster64         (virtualbox, 10.0.0)
debian/contrib-buster64 (virtualbox, 10.1.0)
debian/jessie64         (virtualbox, 8.11.1)
ubuntu/trusty64         (virtualbox, 20190514.0.0)
ubuntu/xenial64         (virtualbox, 20200204.0.0)
```

Some box still show at vagrant box list, even doing the script bellow:

[Vagrant box list](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/remove-all-your-local-vagrant-boxes-bash-command)

```
C:\Users\Marlon\OneDrive (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box list | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs -L 1 vagrant box remove -f
You requested to remove the box 'centos/7'. This box has
multiple providers. You must explicitly select a single
provider to remove with `--provider`.

Available providers: hyperv, virtualbox
You requested to remove the box 'centos/7'. This box has
multiple providers. You must explicitly select a single
provider to remove with `--provider`.

Available providers: hyperv, virtualbox
Removing box 'debian/buster64' (v10.0.0) with provider 'virtualbox'...
Removing box 'debian/contrib-buster64' (v10.1.0) with provider 'virtualbox'...
Removing box 'debian/jessie64' (v8.11.1) with provider 'virtualbox'...
Removing box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) with provider 'virtualbox'...
Removing box 'ubuntu/xenial64' (v20200204.0.0) with provider 'virtualbox'...

C:\Users\Marlon\OneDrive (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box list
centos/7 (hyperv, 1905.1)
centos/7 (virtualbox, 1905.1)
```

To be honest I don't know why some boxes still show above (same provider). I did manually:

```
C:\Users\Marlon\OneDrive (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box remove centos/7 --provider=virtualbox --force
Removing box 'centos/7' (v1905.1) with provider 'virtualbox'...

C:\Users\Marlon\OneDrive (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box remove centos/7 --provider=hyperv --force
Removing box 'centos/7' (v1905.1) with provider 'hyperv'...

C:\Users\Marlon\OneDrive (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box list
There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.
```

I removed all boxes this way, tried several commands without using the file system but unfortunately it seems that is the way...

Comment: I recall hearing it was a Vagrant bug.  You might have luck in the issue tracker: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues

Comment: @LoremIpsum Sorry, tried to do the best to help you. Because I was with many problems with this provisioner. If you see my last questions about version 2.2.6 has a but too. Please point in the issues the exact number so I can reply in the right way. Unfortunatelly I'm trying to do a complete pipeline CI/CD and vagrant will be provisioner for the VMs and it seems that has more bugs than a lamp at night.

Comment: I appreciate you contributing your observations!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with vagrant, I recommend:

1. Don't change parameters of VM in Vagrantfile before destroy a machine
2. If it has happened - You need add an information (vm name) of the machine what you need to destroy and safely destroy it through CMD:

   ```
   vagrant destroy vmname|id
   ```

Note: you don't need to do any manipulations with a box to re-setup a VM actually.

Answer (score -1):

For me, on Windows 10, I just deleted the image in Virtual Box after deleting the main items mentioned above.  This was about 6gb alone.